# prevent keyboard multiselect for gridpanels

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, keyboard-events, extjs-mvc, gridpanel

I want a single select grid, at first I did not include any selection model configuration because that is [**the default**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.RowModel-cfg-mode). This works fine for mouse selections but if I key `SHIFT + END` it selects all records (or `PAGE UP`, `HOME` or `END` has a similar effect).

The selected records are then impossible to deselect without reloading the grid (unless I wanted a grid that is configured with `allowDeselect: true` - which I don't).

Thinking that this was a problem with the ExtJS docs about the default, I then configured the gridpanel with `SINGLE` select explicitly but still had the problem.

I checked out some of their example grids [**here**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/grid-plugins.html), and they all have the same problem - any single select grid will prevent mouse multiselection but can be multiselected with the shift key and `HOME`, `END`, `PAGE UP` or `PAGE DOWN`. And it is then *impossible* to deselect the records.

Seems to be a bug in the framework and I will file a report, but since grids are one of the most commonly used components I assumed someone has a workaround for this.

In desperation I also tried listening to `keypress` globally and stopping the event but that won't even do it. For example, this will log to the console but the event runs anyway:

```
Ext.getDoc().on('keypress', function(event, target) {
    var key = event.getKey();

    // do not allow multiple grid selection
    if (event.shiftKey && (
        key == event.PAGE_UP ||
        key == event.PAGE_DOWN ||
        key == event.HOME ||
        key == event.END)) {

        console.log('unsuccessfully trying to stop the event!');
        event.stopEvent();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.shiftKey = false;
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I do not want to disable all keyboard navigation with `enableKeyNav: false` I just don't want to multiselect with the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
selModel: {
    enableKeyNav: false
},
```

in grid config.
But it was unexpected selection model behavior for me...

**Update**

As a very simple version:

```
selModel: {
    selectRange: function() {
        return false;
    }
},
```

Comment: I should have been more clear in the question. I do want to be able to navigate with the keyboard (just not multiple select with the keyboard)